# Hide solution when using xlop

Tags: equations, packages

I'm using `xlop` to display primary school style addition/subtraction/mul/div problems.

When using `\opadd{1}{2}` for example, It will solve the equation.

How do you hide the solution so it is suitable to give to a student to work out the problems?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change the colour of the output (or result) using `resultstyle=\color{white}`. Sure this will still print the actual output which you can copy-and-paste into a text editor and make it visible, but I don't think kids would do that in a primary school. Moreover, this may only be available electronically for you and not the kids.

Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{xlop}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xlop
\begin{document}
\opadd{1}{2} \quad
\opadd[resultstyle=\color{white},carrystyle=\color{white}]{1}{2}
\end{document}​
```

Since some operations indicate a carry in their presentation, changing `carrystyle` to `\color{white}` is perhaps also suggested, as I've done in my example.

---

Perhaps a more "secure" way of concealing the detail is to provide place holder macros for the bits of information you want to remove:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{xlop}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xlop
\newcommand\placeholder[1]{--}% Print -- regardless of input
\newcommand\gobble[1]{}% Print <nothing> regardless of input
\begin{document}
\opadd{1234}{5678} \quad
\opadd[resultstyle=\placeholder,carrystyle=\color{white}]{1234}{5678} \quad
\opadd[resultstyle=\gobble,carryadd=false]{1234}{5678}
\end{document}​
```

Setting `carrystyle=false` removes the display of carry elements.

---

Multiplication and division adds so-called `intermediary` elements to the operation. These can be removed in a similar way using an appropriate style set by `intermediarystyle`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{xlop}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xlop
\newcommand{\placeholder}[1]{--}% Print -- regardless of the input
\newcommand{\gobble}[1]{}% Print <nothing> regardless of the input
\begin{document}
\opmul{123}{456} \quad
\opmul[resultstyle=\color{white}]{123}{456} \quad
\opmul[resultstyle=\placeholder]{123}{456} \quad
\opmul[resultstyle=\gobble,intermediarystyle=\placeholder,intermediarystyle.3=]{123}{456} \quad
\opmul[resultstyle=\gobble,intermediarystyle=\gobble]{123}{456}

\bigskip

\opdiv{196}{8} \quad
\opdiv[resultstyle=\color{white}]{196}{8} \quad
\opdiv[resultstyle=\placeholder]{196}{8} \quad
\opdiv[resultstyle=\gobble,remainderstyle.2=\placeholder]{196}{8} \quad
\opdiv[resultstyle=\gobble,remainderstyle=\gobble]{196}{8}

\end{document}
```

Selective removal is obtained by adding an index to the `intermediarystyle` or `remainderstyle` based on the level. For example, `intermediarystyle.1` refers to the style of the first intermediary step in the multiplication.

Note that styles act on elements individually. For example, `resultstyle=\placeholder` in the `\opdiv{196}{8}` example prints `--` for each of `2`, `4`, `.` and `5`.

---

If you want more control over the display created by `xlop`, you could create your construction and associated display macros:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@op@top}[4]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{\ }c@{\hspace*{#1}}r}
    & \pgfmathprintnumber{#3} \\
    \smash{\raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}{#2}} & \pgfmathprintnumber{#4} \\ \hline
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\@op@top@bottom}{m s O{1em} m m}{%
  \@op@top{#3}{#1}{#4}{#5}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#2}{}{%
    & \pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{#4\@@op#5}\pgfmathprintnumber{\result}%
  }%
  \end{tabular}%
}
\newcommand{\OpAdd}{\def\@@op{+}\@op@top@bottom{$+$}}
\newcommand{\OpSub}{\def\@@op{-}\@op@top@bottom{$-$}}
\newcommand{\OpMul}{\def\@@op{*}\@op@top@bottom{$\times$}}
\newcommand{\OpDiv}{\def\@@op{/}\@op@top@bottom{$\div$}}
\makeatother
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\OpAdd{1234}{5678} \quad \OpAdd*{1234}{5678} \quad \OpAdd[2em]{1234}{5678} \par \bigskip
\OpSub[1cm]{246}{135} \quad \OpSub*[2pt]{246}{135} \quad \OpSub{246}{135} \par \bigskip
\OpMul{12}{13} \quad \OpMul*[3ex]{12}{13} \quad \OpMul*{12}{13} \par \bigskip
\OpDiv*{1024}{16} \quad \OpDiv{1024}{16} \quad \OpDiv*[3ex]{1024}{16}

\end{document}
```

The above MWE provides `\OpAdd`, `\OpSub`, `\OpMul` and `\OpDiv` that all have the following format: `\<macro>*[<len>]{<op1>}{<op2>}` where the star `*` is optional. It sets `<op1>` and `<op2>` in a `tabular` with the appropriate operator. `<len>` manages the distance between the operator and the operands, while `*` regulates the display of the result/not (using [`pgf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)). Of course, other constructions for "division" is also possible.

Comment: This works wonderfully for \opadd and \opsub.  How do you get rid of the solutions for \opmul and \opdiv

Comment: Also, FWIW,\opadd[resultstyle=\gobble,carrystyle=\gobble]{1234}{5678} \quad  seems to be the best/most secure way to "white out" the solutions and still not have the place holders.

Comment: @jason: See my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry to be annoying, but the multiply and divide leave that whitespace where the information would otherwise be. Is there a way to get it to just be the problem without the whitespace pushing it down?   Also, is there a way to get rid of the answer hline with the multiply?

Comment: @jason: See my updated answer for some manual construction of operations.

Comment: Would you mind contacting me regarding a small amount of contract work if you're interested? see profile.